# Flot load multiple series via ajax

Tags: ajax, json, plugins, flot

I'm trying to load multiple series with ajax, but no success for the moment…

Here is the code that works, with one serie.

In php file :

```
echo '{
 "label": "Marge",
"data": [[1356998400000, 0], [1359676800000, 0], [1362096000000, 0], [1364770800000, 0], [1367362800000, 0], [1370041200000, 0], [1372633200000, 0], [1375311600000, 0], [1377990000000, 0], [1380582000000, 6926.92], [1383264000000, 7236.18], [1385856000000, 10.25]],
"color": "#3a8ce5"
}';
```

In js file :

```
var options = {
        xaxis: {
            min: (new Date(2012, 12, 1)).getTime(),
            max: (new Date(2013, 11, 2)).getTime(),
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: [1, "month"],
            monthNames: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Jui", "Jul", "Aou", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true, 
                fill: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true,
            }
        },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
    };


    var data = [];

    $.plot("#flot-audience", data, options);

    var dataurl = 'ajax/stats-ca.php';

    function onDataReceived(series) {


        data.push(series);      

        $.plot("#flot-audience", data, options);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: dataurl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: onDataReceived
    });
```

When I try to change the php code to the next code, nothing is showing on the graph and the y-axis goes from -1.0 to 1.0.

```
echo '{
"stats": [ 
       {
       "label": "CA",
       "data": [[1356998400000, 0], [1359676800000, 0], [1362096000000, 0], [1364770800000, 0], [1367362800000, 0], [1370041200000, 0], [1372633200000, 0], [1375311600000, 0], [1377990000000, 0], [1380582000000, 24837.53], [1383264000000, 20210.38], [1385856000000, 952.72]],
       "color": "#3a8ce5" 
       },
       {
       "label": "Marge",
       "data": [[1356998400000, 0], [1359676800000, 0], [1362096000000, 0], [1364770800000, 0], [1367362800000, 0], [1370041200000, 0], [1372633200000, 0], [1375311600000, 0], [1377990000000, 0], [1380582000000, 6926.92], [1383264000000, 7236.18], [1385856000000, 10.25]],
       "color": "#fa8ce5"
       }
     ]
 }';
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks very much

Comment: What does your JS code look like when using multiple series?  You've changed it to use 'series.stats' instead of just 'series', I assume?

Comment: Thanks! I tried 'data.stats' but not 'series.stats'… Thank you again

Comment: I'll turn this into an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use series.stats instead of just series, since your incoming data now has that extra level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra set of brackets when you are pushing your data series. Have a look at this mock up http://jsfiddle.net/KMTjZ/9/. I alerted the two values out so you could have a look.

```
//Push
alert(JSON.stringify(data));

//Without
alert(JSON.stringify(stats));
```